# Symfony Form Collection with Fixed Fields

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I’m having trouble implementing a form collection that only consists of fixed fields, i.e. allow_add & allow_delete are false.

I have a Board entity that consists of a number of properties including a ‘components’ property which is a many-to-many relationship to a Component entity. The form for entering a Board will have a Components section, but this is not a case where a user can add any component they like. Instead, they will be presented with a fixed list of component types and can then select the component from a drop down list. For example:

- Component A: [drop down – criteria A]
- Component B: [drop down –
  criteria B]

I have this partially working. I am able to add the component fields in BoardType and generate the drop down menu with the desired criteria. I can submit the form and the appropriate database fields are persisted. All is good. When I go to edit an existing board…different story. Two things happen that are undesirable:

1. The existing components for that board are rendered with all their fields to be edited. The name of the component, the manufacturer, component type, etc. I don’t want any of this to be available to the user. I’m hoping this is just a rendering problem.
2. My fixed component fields are still displayed but the drop down lists have reset to their placeholder values and do not reflect what is actually stored in database.

Now the code (shortened for brevity):

Board Entity

```
/**
 * Board
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Board", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="type_id", columns={"type_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
    class Board extends Baseentity
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string|null
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="customer_board_name", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
         */
        private $customerBoardName;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Component")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="BoardComponentJoin", 
         *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="board_id")},
         *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(unique=true)})
         */
        private $components;


        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->components = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        public function getId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function getCustomerBoardName(): ?string
        {
            return $this->customerBoardName;
        }

        public function setCustomerBoardName(?string $customerBoardName): self
        {
            $this->customerBoardName = $customerBoardName;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getComponents()
        {
            return $this->components;
        }

        public function addComponent(Component $component)
        {
            $this->components->add($component);
        }

        public function removeComponent(Component $component)
        {
            $this->components->removeElement($component);
        }
```

Component Entity

```
/**
 * Component
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Component", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="type_id", columns={"type_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="company_id", columns={"company_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Component extends Baseentity
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \ComponentDevicetype
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ComponentDevicetype")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var \Company
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $company;
```

BoardType

```
class BoardType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
           ->add('customerBoardName', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Name (Customer)'])
        ;

        $builder
            ->add('components', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => EmbedComponentType::class,
                'allow_add' => false,
                'allow_delete' => false])
        ;

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {

            $form = $event->getForm();

            $form->get('components')
                ->add('ddr', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => Component::class,
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('comp')
                        ->where('comp.type = 1')
                        ->orderBy('comp.name', 'ASC');},
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'placeholder' => 'Choose Component...',
                    'label' => 'DDR',
                    'required' => false])
                ->add('flash', EntityType::class, [
                  'class' => Component::class,
                  'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                      return $er->createQueryBuilder('comp')
                      ->where('comp.type = 6')
                      ->orderBy('comp.name', 'ASC');},
                  'choice_label' => 'name',
                  'placeholder' => 'Choose Component...',
                  'label' => 'Flash',
                  'required' => false]);
        }); 
}
```

EmbedComponentType

```
class EmbedComponentType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    { 
        $builder
            ->add('name', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Component::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('comp')
                    ->orderBy('comp.name', 'ASC');},
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'Choose Component...',]);
    }
}
```

My questions:

1. When editing a board, how can I get the Component drop down lists to accurately reflect what’s in the database?
2. <strike>How to prevent the ComponentType fields from rendering when editing a board?</strike>
3. Am I even approaching this “fixed collection” concept correctly?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Show us the Twig form you are using to render the fields (on the page that you don't want to render them _all_)

Comment: I fixed the rendering (sort of) by creating a new EmbedComponentType form which only has the fields I want - much easier. I think I found where I have a major gap. There's no way to map a component to a form field when you go to edit an existing board. It only knows there are components. It doesn't know what they are. I see that Symfony has a DataMapper might be well suited for this. Am I getting warmer?